# SQL drastically increasing SUMS from multiple JOINS

Tags: java, sql, oracle, join

I need to join multiple tables in the below SQL statement. Compared to the original statement the sums are increasing the counts drastically when I added these joins:

```
LEFT outer join pp_sku_pattern skupattern 
ON skupattern.sp_sku_no = item.sku_no

LEFT outer join si_pi_shrinkages_hist pishretail 
ON pish_inventory_date = :inventoryDate
AND
pish_sku_no = item.sku_no
AND
ROWNUM = 1 

Left outer join si_store_cycle_counts cyclecounts 
ON cyclecounts.scc_str_no = :storeNbr
AND
scc_sku = item.sku_no
```

Original SQL statement with dashboard data view:
[Original SQL statement with dashboard data view image (accurate counts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HILt.png)

New SQL statement with dashboard data view:
[New SQL statement with dashboard data view image (inaccurate counts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oAfN.png)

Original SQL statement with correct sum counts:

```
SELECT dept.dept_code,
       dept.dept_desc,
       var.sprvh_inventory_date,
       var.sprvh_store,
       var.sprvh_sku,
       brand.br_name,
       item.sku_style,
       SUM(var.sprvh_phys_qty),
       SUM(var.sprvh_book_qty),
       SUM(var.sprvh_curr_variance),
       SUM(var.sprvh_hist_variance),
       SUM(var.sprvh_revision_number)
FROM   si_pi_research_var_hist var
       left outer join pp_stock_keeping_units item
                    ON var.sprvh_sku = item.sku_no
                       AND var.sprvh_company_code = item.sku_company_code
       left outer join pp_departments dept
                    ON dept.dept_company_code = item.sku_company_code
                       AND dept.dept_code = item.sku_dept_code
       left outer join pp_brands brand
                    ON brand.br_id = item.sku_br_id
WHERE  var.sprvh_inventory_date = :inventoryDate
       AND VAR.sprvh_store = :storeNbr
       AND ( ( var.sprvh_phys_qty IS NOT NULL
               AND var.sprvh_phys_qty <> 0 )
              OR ( var.sprvh_book_qty IS NOT NULL
                   AND var.sprvh_book_qty <> 0 )
              OR ( var.sprvh_curr_variance IS NOT NULL
                   AND var.sprvh_curr_variance <> 0 )
              OR ( var.sprvh_hist_variance IS NOT NULL
                   AND var.sprvh_hist_variance <> 0 ) )
GROUP  BY dept.dept_code,
          dept.dept_desc,
          var.sprvh_inventory_date,
          var.sprvh_store,
          var.sprvh_sku,
          brand.br_name,
          item.sku_style
HAVING SUM(var.sprvh_curr_variance) <> 0
        OR SUM(var.sprvh_hist_variance) <> 0
ORDER  BY Abs(SUM(var.sprvh_curr_variance))
```

Full new SQL statement that produces incorrect sum counts:

```
SELECT dept.dept_code,
       dept.dept_desc,
       var.sprvh_inventory_date,
       var.sprvh_store,
       var.sprvh_sku,
       brand.br_name,
       item.sku_style,
       skupattern.sp_pattern,
       pishretail.pish_retail,
       cyclecounts.scc_reason_process_flag,
       SUM(var.sprvh_phys_qty),
       SUM(var.sprvh_book_qty),
       SUM(var.sprvh_curr_variance),
       SUM(var.sprvh_hist_variance),
       SUM(var.sprvh_revision_number)
FROM   si_pi_research_var_hist var
       left outer join pp_stock_keeping_units item
                    ON var.sprvh_sku = item.sku_no
                       AND var.sprvh_company_code = item.sku_company_code
       left outer join pp_departments dept
                    ON dept.dept_company_code = item.sku_company_code
                       AND dept.dept_code = item.sku_dept_code
       left outer join pp_brands brand
                    ON brand.br_id = item.sku_br_id
       left outer join pp_sku_pattern skupattern
                    ON skupattern.sp_sku_no = item.sku_no
       left outer join si_pi_shrinkages_hist pishretail
                    ON pishretail.pish_inventory_date = :inventoryDate
                       AND pish_sku_no = item.sku_no
                       AND ROWNUM = 1
       left outer join si_store_cycle_counts cyclecounts
                    ON cyclecounts.scc_str_no = :storeNbr
                       AND scc_sku = item.sku_no
WHERE  var.sprvh_inventory_date = :inventoryDate
       AND VAR.sprvh_store = :storeNbr
       AND ( ( var.sprvh_phys_qty IS NOT NULL
               AND var.sprvh_phys_qty <> 0 )
              OR ( var.sprvh_book_qty IS NOT NULL
                   AND var.sprvh_book_qty <> 0 )
              OR ( var.sprvh_curr_variance IS NOT NULL
                   AND var.sprvh_curr_variance <> 0 )
              OR ( var.sprvh_hist_variance IS NOT NULL
                   AND var.sprvh_hist_variance <> 0 ) )
GROUP  BY dept.dept_code,
          dept.dept_desc,
          var.sprvh_inventory_date,
          var.sprvh_store,
          var.sprvh_sku,
          brand.br_name,
          item.sku_style,
          skupattern.sp_pattern,
          pishretail.pish_retail,
          cyclecounts.scc_reason_process_flag
HAVING SUM(var.sprvh_curr_variance) <> 0
        OR SUM(var.sprvh_hist_variance) <> 0
ORDER  BY Abs(SUM(var.sprvh_curr_variance))
```

Question: How to keep original statement sums the same in the new SQL statement with 3 new joins?

Comment: Well what is the question? You know that if you join to a table where the join key is not unique you multiplies the current records which *change the sum*. So you'll have to *prohibit* it in the new joins e.g. with adding the `rownum = 1` predicate to the two other joins where it is missing.

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to read the query like that?  At least format it.  You can format it [here](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Question is: How to keep original statement sums the same? Thank you for this answer I will try adding rownum = 1 predicate to the two other joins where it is missing, and will let you know :)

Comment: @OldProgrammer Please let me know how I can format it better, I am new :)

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thank you, I have updated the format :)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I added rownum = 1 to each of the new joins and still have same sum issue

Comment: Say, you have five rows with `sp_sku_no = 1` in `skupattern`. If you join the sum with this ID will quintuple. What you need is a new column , say `rn`, that is calculated so, that it returns only unique values of the join key when constrained with `rn = 1`, e.g. `row_number() over (partition by sp_sku_no order by something..` With the `order by` you define which one of the five rows you will choose.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thank you, so what exactly in the statement above would you change?

Comment: Better approach - use the original query as a *subquery* and join the **result** with the three new tables. So the `sum`s will remain unchnaged they will be only *replicated* in more rows. Ask yourself what do you want to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem going from non-unique values you using for join.
For example:

```
 left outer join si_store_cycle_counts cyclecounts
                    ON cyclecounts.scc_str_no = :storeNbr
                       AND scc_sku = item.sku_no
```

As first. Try to use table aliases for every table field.

```
 left outer join si_store_cycle_counts cyclecounts
                    ON cyclecounts.scc_str_no = :storeNbr
                       AND cyclecounts.scc_sku = item.sku_no
```

Second. Check each join condition. By example. If join returning more then one row from joind table for one row from si_pi_research_var_hist its place for fix.

Comment: Trying this now